# Memory leak in NSImage conversion when using autoreleasepool

Tags: macos, xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.mac

I have a memory leak in my program where I convert a NSImage to a  byte  array. I tried to dispose of all variables and use an autoreleasepool:

```
void LoadNewScreenImage()
    {
        byte[] pixels;
        using (NSAutoreleasePool autoreleasepool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
        using (NSImage nsimage = computerInterface.GetComputerScreenForDisplayIndex(0))
        using (CGImage image = nsimage.CGImage)
        using (CGDataProvider dataProvider = image.DataProvider)
        using (NSData data = dataProvider.CopyData())
        {
            pixels = new byte[data.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Bytes, pixels, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
        }
    }
```

where `computerInterface.GetComputerScreenForDisplayIndex(0)` is a native function which returns a screenshot of the computer:

```
-(NSImage*)getComputerScreenForDisplayIndex:(NSInteger) displayIndex
{
    NSImage* computerScreenshot = 0;

    CGDisplayCount displayCount=0;

    if(self.displays ==  nil)
    {

        self.error = CGDisplayNoErr;
        displayCount = 0;

        //allocate enough memory to hold all the display ids that we have
        self.displays = (CGDirectDisplayID *)calloc((size_t)displayCount, sizeof(CGDirectDisplayID));


        //how many displays do we have?
        self.error = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, NULL, &displayCount);
    }

    //if there are displays
    if(self.error !=  CGDisplayNoErr)
        return 0;


    //get the list of active displays
    self.error = CGGetActiveDisplayList(displayCount, self.displays, &displayCount);

    self.image = CGDisplayCreateImage(self.displays[displayIndex]);

    computerScreenshot = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.image size:(NSSize){(CGFloat)CGImageGetWidth(self.image),(CGFloat)(CGImageGetHeight(self.image))}];

    CGImageRelease(self.image);
    return computerScreenshot;
}
```

I've tested this native function in a pure objective-c program and I don't get any memory leaks. Does anyone know what is causing this leak or how I could get rid of it? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the thread context of `LoadNewScreenImage`, is it on the main looper, or in an async threadpool, managed thread?, ....

Comment: @SushiHangover the function call to `LoadNewScreenImage` is performed on the main thread